# Prove $ \exists y \in S, \forall x \in S, p(x,y) \implies \exists y \in S, p(y,y) $

Tags: logic

I tried it as shown below but I'm not 100% sure about it. Can anybody tell me if it has any errors or is missing something?

Consider $\exists y \in S, \forall x \in S, p(x,y)$

Let $y_0 \in S \:\: \text{s.t.}\:\: \forall x \in S, p(x,y_0)$

Let $x_0 \in S \:\: \text{s.t.}\:\: x_0 = y_0 $

$p(x_0, y_0) \implies p(y_0, y_0) $

$\therefore \exists y \in S, \forall x \in S, p(x,y) \implies \exists y \in S, p(y,y) $

I need proof for the following one as well.
$   \forall x \in S, \exists y \in S, p(x,y) \implies \exists y \in S, p(y,y) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let $y_0$ ..." is wrong. When you instantiate a variable bound by an existential quantifier, you have to substitute **all** its occurrences. You missed one.

"Let $x_0$ ..." is valid but not justified. Instead you should have said "Let $x_0 = y_0 \in S$". Anyway you will see below that you don't need $x_0$.

Your line after that is correct but not enough if you want a completely formal proof. "$A \Rightarrow B$" is not as strong as "$B$". Don't use the implication symbol unless you only want to state that the implication is true. Instead you needed to instantiate the "$x$" in "$\forall x \in S \, ( p(...) )$" with the value $y_0$. Then you will get "$p(y_0,y_0)$" directly (with no implication symbol anywhere), and hence "$\exists y \in S \, ( p(y,y) )$".

Comment: @S.Dan: Like what? Do you understand what I said in my answer? Your comment to Mauro is still wrong. You should not anyhow use implications, if you want a proper formal proof.

Comment: @user21820- Actually the comment was for your answer. I mixed up the two.

Comment: @S.Dan: Yes it's not quite right.. For example if you want to prove "B" from "A" you do not write "A implies B" and stop. In this case you have a universal quantification, which when you instantiate you immediately get what I wrote in quotes in my answer, and you should not write any implication symbol.

Comment: Right. No implying. It goes like $y_0 \in S $ and then $ p(y_0, y_0) $  Is it so?

Comment: @S.Dan: Perfect! I'm particular about the notation because I've seen the implication symbol being misused a lot in lower level maths courses, but it actually has a precise meaning in logic.

Answer (score 1):

The steps in your proof are not so clear to me.

You started assuming :

> $∃y∀xp(x,y)$

and then assumed an $y_0$ such that :

> $\forall x p(x, y_0)$.

Then you have to use the same $y_0$ to "instantiate" the universal quantifier, obtaining:

> $p(y_0,y_0)$.

If you use a different *term*, like your $x_0$, you get : $p(x_0,y_0) \rightarrow p(y_0,y_0)$ which, in general, is not true [if John is taller than Mike, does not follows that Mike is taller then itself].

Having done this, we have to introduce $\exists$, getting :

> $\exists yp(y,y)$.

Up to now we have obtained :

> > $∃y∀xp(x,y) \vdash \exists yp(y,y)$.

Finally, by $\rightarrow$-introduction, we conclude with :

> > $\vdash ∃y∀xp(x,y) \rightarrow \exists yp(y,y)$.

*Comment*

You have not specified your proof system; thus, I've used *Natural Deduction*.

If your proof system is an *Hilbert-style* (like Enderton's) we have to use the *axiom* : $\forall x \alpha(x) \rightarrow \alpha(x/t)$ after the second line, to get : $p(y_0,y_0)$ from : $\forall x p(x,y_0) \rightarrow p(y_0,y_0)$.

---

Regarding : $∀x∃yp(x,y) \rightarrow ∃yp(y,y)$, you cannot prove it, because it is **not** valid.

Consider an *interpretation* with *domain* the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* and interpret the binary *predicate* $p(x,y)$ as "$x$ is less than $y$".

We have that $n < n+1$; thus, $\forall x \exists y(x < y)$ but it is not true that $n < n$.

Comment: So it has to be like this? -Consider $\exists y \in S, \forall x \in S, p(x,y)$

Let $y_0 \in S \:\: \text{s.t.}\:\: \forall x \in S, p(x,y_0)$


$ \forall x \in S p(x,y) \implies  p(y_0, y_0) $ 

$\therefore \exists y \in S, \forall x \in S, p(x,y) \implies \exists y \in S, p(y,y) $

Comment: NO. The assumption is : ∃y∈S,∀x∈S,p(x,y) ; then you apply $\exists$-elimination to derive : $∀x∈S,p(x,y_0)$. Up to now is correct, but then you have to use the correct form of universal instantiation, which is : $∀x∈Sp(x,y_0) \rightarrow p(y_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Oh yeah i missed da sub0 when copying and pasting. Then is it ok?